# When and why to use Scanner?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and was reading different ways to handle input and output. From what I've read, the various strategies boil down to two things i.e.

1. Reading / Writing by byte (`FileInputStream`, `FileOutputStream`).
2. Reading / Writing by character (`FileReader`, `FileWriter`).

But where does `Scanner` fit into the picture? An example use case would be good.

Comment: try [google](https://www.google.co.in/#q=scanner+in+java+stackoverflow) before posting questions, it would save time for all.

Comment: @Jens If javadoc was sufficient I wouldn't have been here. Many times things which seems obvious to you might not seem same to others. Thanks.

Comment: Also, `Scanner` reads whole input at once or searches the `token` one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a **Scanner** if you want to read tokens

Use a **FileReader** when reading streams of characters

Use a **FileInputReader** when reading binary files.

Scanner:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be
>   converted into values of different types using the various next
>   methods. [Scanner - JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

And for Filereader and FileInputReader:

> FileReader is meant for reading streams of characters. For reading
>   streams of raw bytes, consider using a FileInputStream. [FileReader -javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)

Example for a scanner:

```
String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";
   Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*fish\\s*");
   System.out.println(s.nextInt());
   System.out.println(s.nextInt());
   System.out.println(s.next());
   System.out.println(s.next());
 s.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Scanner is a higher level class used to read input by tokens.

What is a token? For the class Scanner a token can be a primitive value and some special object:

- long (with nextLong)
- int (with nextInt)
- short (with nextShort)
- byte (with nextByte)
- boolean (with nextBoolean)
- BigDecimal (with nextBigDecimal)
- float (with nextFloat)
- double (with nextDouble)

In addition it is possible to read a whole line with `nextLine`.

Comment: So, **scanner** reads whole input stream or fetches token one at a time?

Comment: They consume characters reading the tokens. They don't consume the whole stream in one step.

Answer (score 1):

The Scanner class is a class in `java.util` which allows the user to read values of various types. There are two constructors that are particularly useful: one takes an `InputStream` object as a parameter and the other takes a `FileReader` object as a parameter.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  // System.in is an InputStream
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("myFile"));// If the file ≥myFile≤ is not found, a FileNotFoundException is thrown.
```

Various Methods:

- `int nextInt()`: Returns the next token as an int. If the next token is not an integer, InputMismatchException is thrown.
- `long nextLong()`: Returns the next token as a long. If the next token is not an integer, InputMismatchException is thrown.
- `float nextFloat()`: Returns the next token as a float. If the next token is not a float or is out of range, InputMismatchException is thrown.
- `double nextDouble()`: Returns the next token as a long. If the next token is not a float or is out of range, InputMismatchException is thrown.
- String next(): Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner and returns it as a string; a token is usually ended by whitespace such as a blank or line break. If not token exists, NoSuchElementException is thrown.
- `String nextLine()`: Returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end.
- `void close()`: Closes the scanner.

The Scanner looks for tokens in the input. A token is a series of characters that ends with what Java calls whitespace. Thus, if we read a line that has a series of numbers separated by blanks, the scanner will take each number as a separate token.